# Python script for parsing ldap logs for getting Searcches/Binds

Tags: python

I am trying to create a script for parsing ldap logs and get number of binds/searches per user. Let me explain the problem statement in detail below.

The log file contains lines with BIND REQs and SEARCH REQs and only common thing that connects these two lines to a session is a connection id.

Every time a user binds to the ldap server he will get a unique connection id and a new BIND REQ line will be created in the log file, so if a user binds multiple times and every time he will get a multiple connection id. So if a user test1 binds 4 times a day he will be having 4 connection ids like 1234, 3345, 5643, 6642. So for finding the No of Binds by a user i simply need to count the connection ids and i am done

Now for for every bind request made (connection id) user can search 0 or more times. So to count no.of searches for a particular user first i have to create a dictionary which has UID as key and list of connection ids as the value. Then for every key(which is every uid) i need to count the searches for every connection id and then sum them all up for final value. So taking that example of user test1 the output would be calculated like below

test1-> [1234, 3345, 5643, 6642] - So for binds all i need to do is len(d[test1])

But for Searches the case would be more tricky... lets say below are number of search lines for these connection ids.

```
SEARCH REQ.......conn=1234 op=1......
SEARCH REQ.......conn=1234 op=2......
SEARCH REQ.......conn=1234 op=3......
SEARCH REQ.......conn=1234 op=4......
SEARCH REQ.......conn=3345 op=1......
SEARCH REQ.......conn=3345 op=2......
SEARCH REQ.......conn=3345 op=3......
SEARCH REQ.......conn=3345 op=4......
SEARCH REQ.......conn=3345 op=5......
SEARCH REQ.......conn=5643 op=1......
SEARCH REQ.......conn=6642 op=1......
SEARCH REQ.......conn=6642 op=2......
SEARCH REQ.......conn=6642 op=3......
```

So the result should be calculated like connid-1234 -> 4 + connid-3345 -> 5+connid-5643 ->1+connid-6642->3

So total no of searches for test1 = 13

Below is my code,

```
import os,re,datetime
from collections import defaultdict

d=defaultdict(list)
k=defaultdict(list)
start_time=datetime.datetime.now()

fh = open("C:\\access","r").readlines()
fh1 = open("C:\\access","r").read()
pat=re.compile('conn=([\d]*).*dn=([^,]*)')

for line in fh:
    if re.search(" BIND REQ ",line):
        conid,uid=re.search(pat,line).group(1,2)
        d[uid].append(conid)


for key in d:
    for con in d[key]:
        count = re.findall('SEARCH REQ.*'+con,fh1)
        k[key].append((con,len(count)))


for key in k:
    print("No of bind  ",key," = ",len(k[key]))

for key in k:
    print("Number of searches by ",key, " : ",sum([i[1] for i in k[key]]))

fh.close()
end_time=datetime.datetime.now()
print("Total time taken - {}".format(end_time-start_time))
```

The problem with this is that for larger files say more than 20M it takes lot of time and i feel the piece of code that is causing this is below line

```
count = re.findall(r'SEARCH REQ.*(?=conn='+con+').*',fh1)
```

I am trying to think and find out a way to minimize the loop count or maybe there is some better way to do this which i do not know being a python beginner. So i would sincerely seek some guidance/advise here.

Comment: [finditer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer) scans iteratively through the file. maybe that helps?

Comment: @hiroprotagonist i tried that as well but it did not help a bit....

Comment: Can anyone help me on this issue,,,, i see no comment at all from last 24 hours !!!